# Function diverges but area under curve is finite?

Tags: integration, functions, area, curves

I have a curve given by $f(x)=\frac{x}{b^2}(1-\frac{x^2}{b^2})^{-1/2}$ for $x \in (0,b)$. Upon integration, I get that the area under the curve on the interval $(t, b)$ is given by $F(t) =\sqrt{1-\frac{t^2}{b^2}}$.

The value of $f(x)$ is $0$ for $x=0$ but grows and diverges to positive infinity as $x \to b$, but the area under the curve  on the interval $(0, b)$ gives a unit area. How can a diverging curve have a finite area? Any help?

Ps: its not a homework question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your question title and description do not match.

Comment: Actually, homework questions are acceptable IF you've shown your work, and need hints, not the whole solution.

Comment: Really sorry I changed my question last minute because I realized my mistake. The title should be unbounded curve but finite area.

Comment: It's a good question. The short answer is, *because it does* based on the way we measure integration - which is the limit of a sum of areas of rectangles. Now, not all functions have finite area if they diverge at a point, for example, $\tan(x)$ at $ pi/2$. Some functions do, some functions don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your title's question, that negative sign in $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{b^2}}$ is perfectly alright. Technically there should be a $+C$ appended. If $C\geq1$, then $f(x)\geq 0$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Also, since $f$ is increasing from $0\leq x<1$. This means any measuring of area under $f'$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ (for any constant $C$) will be positive and the world makes sense.

It is indeed strange that in mathematics (and in nature), things can have infinite perimeter but finite area (take fractals for instance).

Or instead, take geometric series' an example. You're adding an infinite number of terms (a diverging number of terms!) but the whole sum can converge.

In other words, even though $f$ approaches $+\infty$ as $x$ aproaches $b$, the graph attempts to hug the line $x=b$ so tightly that the area essentially vanishes as fast (or faster) than the terms of a converging geometric series do.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of it. The thing is that the given function is a probability density function. Im trying to understand what happens when $x$ is close to $b$. If the curve is diverging does that mean the probability of sample space increases near $b$? Means are event close to $b$ have higher probability of occurrence?

Comment: @user146021 I see your confusion, I've never dealt with probability density functions where the probability density can surpass 100% (in this case surpassing to infinity). A seemingly very non-intuitive situation. You are correct though, there is a great lenience towards the event occurring near $x=b$.

Comment: Unlike a probability mass function, the value of a PDF can be above 1, because the value of the PDF is ***not*** a probability. With a PDF, the probability of the variable being in some interval is the area under the curve of the PDF above that interval, i.e. the integral of the PDF over that interval.

Answer (score 1):

"How can a diverging curve have a finite area?" *Because it can*.

Let's say, more generally, that $g(x)$ is a differentiable function that has a point of divergence $b>0$.

$g(x) \rightarrow \infty$, as $x \rightarrow b$ implies the area under $g$ between $a$ and $b$ is either finite or infinite. In order to figure out which one for the specific function $g$, you have to carry out the integration between $a$ and $b$ of that function.

For example, the function you give has finite area, whereas $\tan(x)$ between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ has infinite area.

As $x$ tends to $b$ from below(left), whether or not the area of $g(x)$ between $0$ and $x$ increases by a *small* amount vs a *large* amount, depends on how quickly the gradient of $g(x)$ increases as $x$ tends to $b$.

You could instead think of it as a sum of rectangles with width $x_i$ with $x_i \rightarrow 0$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$, and height(length) $y_i$ with $y_i \rightarrow \infty$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$. Note that this is not the usual way we do integration, but you can get the exact area this way.

Then the area is the limit of $ \sum x_i \cdot y_i$

which boils down to an indeterminate of the form $0 \times \infty$, which can be finite or infinite.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: This surely is counter-intuitive, though the answer needs to edited because the height does not tend to infinity for each $i$.

Comment: "The height does not tend to infinity for each $i$". If you read from, "You can also think of it as a sum of rectangles..." onwards more carefully, you'll see I'm not doing usual integration there, but taking rectangles of smaller and smaller width.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but it can be improved.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of it. The thing is that the given function is a probability density function. Im trying to understand what happens when x is close to b. If the curve is diverging does that mean the probability of sample space increases near b? Means are event close to b have higher probability of occurrence?

Comment: UmbQbify -Key20 How can it be improved?

Comment: @user146021 I think I would need to see the whole question. Also, this does sound like homework.

Comment: Tbh this is inverse gamma function of relativity. I took gamma function and tried to find a PDF which would yield inverse gamma function upon integration. At $x=b$ the PDF goes unbounded to infinity. Does that mean probability of event at $b$ are more likely to occur?

Comment: The PDF does follow rules such as total probability or area should be unity. My only concern is why it gets unbounded and why do event near $b$ have higher probability to occur?

Comment: No idea. Maybe ask it as a new question.

Comment: @user146021, if the random variable is continuous, with the given PDF, then the probability of “event ***at*** $b$”, assuming that means “$x=b$”, is zero. But if you’re asking, “Is the probability of a continuous random variable being in an interval of fixed length $\delta$ higher for intervals which have a higher average value of the PDF?”, yes. As for “why do event near $b$ have higher probability”, that’s more of a question about your system, i.e. whatever that random variable represents.