# PDF goes unbounded. Is probability of event infinite?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, curves

This is follow up from here: [Curve above $x$ axis but area is negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3748395/806659)

I have a PDF which has unit area but it goes unbounded to infinity at $x=b$ (please refer to attached link). Does it mean the probability of events near $b$ is infinite?

Comment: Probabilities never exceed $1$.

Comment: Notice that in the case of continuous probability distributions, the actual probability corresponds to an integral over the function. A PDF must satisfy that the total "area" (or integral) is equal to 1, so therefore any integral within there must be less than one.

Comment: "*probability of events near $b$*"  Go back and recall the definition of a PDF for a continuous random variable and how to calculate the probability of an event using a PDF.  While the *instantaneous* density might grow quite large, recall that calculating an area we not only take the *height* into account but *also the width.*. You seem to be forgetting the *width* here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: The PDF has area integral equal to 1. Im just curious about the divergence. Im starting to get a feel about how apparent infinite areas turn out to be finite due to increasingly diminishing width of rectangle to sum it. But the divergence part still throws me off. Any insight/help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Assume $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}-\ln x&,\quad 0< x\le 1\\0&,\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$then the CDF would be $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
0&,\quad x\le 0\\
x-x\ln x&,\quad 0< x\le 1\\1&,\quad x>1\end{cases}$$which is bounded, but of astonishingly high ascent near $x=0$.

Comment: Is there any significance or meaning of having a high ascent near $x=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Using axiomatic approach, probability is defined as Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on the subsets/intervals of a closed interval of real numbers, $[0,1]$, sample space $\Omega$. This measure/probability is equal to the length of such subset/interval. The 'smallest' Lebesgue measure is on isolated points ($0$), because the distance from the point to itself is $0$. The 'largest' Lebesgue measure is on the whole sample space $\Omega$. Again, by definition, it can't exceed $1$. So the probability/Lebesgue measure is strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Is there any significance or meaning of having a high ascent near x=0?

Comment: 'probability' is just a length of an interval, they don't have 'high ascent near $x=0$'